# UE4 Closest enemy targeting

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, targeting

I currently am making a game with UE4 where I have AI players as well as 1 local player. I'm trying to make a Team Deathmatch gamemode. I've got everything done but I have one problem. I need my `AIController` class to target the nearest 'enemy' (the enemy pawns have teams on them) so basically the closest actor of my pawn class that isn't on the `AIController`'s team. What is an elegant way of implementing this?

What I do so far is spawn all controllers and pawns in the gamemode class and store references to those on every spawned pawn. Then once one dies a delegate fires off removing the killed pawn reference from all the pawns that are still alive. Vice versa for re-spawning. Then each tick (which is Totally gross and I know this is wrong) all the pawns iterate through their respective enemy pawn references and get the distance to the referenced pawns and return whatever pawn had the closest distance.

Before asking this here. I did a lot of searches on the web for solutions to this problem but the closest I could get is a tab targeting system you can buy on in the workshop.

I'm fairly new to the entirety of developing games (started studying C++ and UE4 2 months ago). So if there is an obvious solution, I am very sorry.

Edit:

I've taken a new approach. I iterate through all the objects of class `ATank` every frame and get their distance and compare it to the previous calculated distance. when its a smaller distance it sets the new pending target. This does it fine. The problem is when a tank's hp reaches 0 it is destroyed.

```
ATank* ATankAIController::GetClosestEnemyTank()
{
    ATank* PendingTarget = TargetTank;
    for (TObjectIterator<ATank> Itr; Itr; ++Itr) //for all tanks in the world
    {
        if (Itr->GetTeam() != Team)
        {
            if (PendingTarget == nullptr) { PendingTarget = *Itr; continue; }
            if (Itr->GetDistanceTo(PossessedTank) < PendingTarget->GetDistanceTo(PossessedTank))
            {
                PendingTarget = *Itr;
            }
        }
    }
    return PendingTarget;
}


float ATank::TakeDamage(float DamageAmount, FDamageEvent const & DamageEvent, AController * EventInstigator, AActor * DamageCauser)
{
    int32 DamagePoints = FPlatformMath::RoundToInt(DamageAmount);
    int32 DamageToApply = FMath::Clamp<int32>(DamagePoints, 0, TankCurrentHealth);

    TankCurrentHealth -= DamageToApply;

    if (TankCurrentHealth == 0) 
    { 
        OnTankDeathEvent.Broadcast(this); 
    }
    return DamageToApply;
}

void ATankAIController::OnTankDeath(AActor* TankThatDied)
{
    UnPossess();
    Spawnpoint->bInUse = false;
    Cast<ATeamDeatmatchGameMode>(GetWorld()->GetAuthGameMode())->OnRespawnRequestEvent.Broadcast(this);
    TankThatDied->Destroy();
}
```

The problem is there are 12 tanks in total. When one dies at that split moment where in the iteration the distance gets calculated I get an exception and the game crashes. At least that's what I think it is...

Here are the catches of the exception by Visual Studio and crash report of Unreal.

[image: VSException1]
[image: VS Callstack and locals]

> Access violation - code c0000005 (first/second chance not available)
>
> UE4Editor_Engine!AActor::GetDistanceTo()
>   [d:\build++ue4+release-4.19+compile\sync\engine\source\runtime\engine\private\actor.cpp:4413] UE4Editor_BattleTank_727!ATankAIController::GetClosestEnemyTank()
>   [f:\unreal
>   projects\battle-tank\battletank\source\battletank\private\tankaicontroller.cpp:70]
>   UE4Editor_BattleTank_727!ATankAIController::Tick() [f:\unreal
>   projects\battle-tank\battletank\source\battletank\private\tankaicontroller.cpp:37]
>   UE4Editor_Engine!AController::TickActor()
>   [d:\build++ue4+release-4.19+compile\sync\engine\source\runtime\engine\private\leveltick.cpp:408]
>   UE4Editor_Engine!FActorTickFunction::ExecuteTick()
>   [d:\build++ue4+release-4.19+compile\sync\engine\source\runtime\engine\private\actor.cpp:134] UE4Editor_Engine!FTickFunctionTask::DoTask()
>   [d:\build++ue4+release-4.19+compile\sync\engine\source\runtime\engine\private\ticktaskmanager.cpp:273]
>   UE4Editor_Engine!TGraphTask::ExecuteTask()
>   [d:\build++ue4+release-4.19+compile\sync\engine\source\runtime\core\public\async\taskgraphinterfaces.h:829]
>   UE4Editor_Core!FNamedTaskThread::ProcessTasksNamedThread()
>   [d:\build++ue4+release-4.19+compile\sync\engine\source\runtime\core\private\async\taskgraph.cpp:665]
>   UE4Editor_Core!FNamedTaskThread::ProcessTasksUntilQuit()
>   [d:\build++ue4+release-4.19+compile\sync\engine\source\runtime\core\private\async\taskgraph.cpp:574]
>   UE4Editor_Core!FTaskGraphImplementation::WaitUntilTasksComplete()
>   [d:\build++ue4+release-4.19+compile\sync\engine\source\runtime\core\private\async\taskgraph.cpp:1355]
>   UE4Editor_Engine!FTickTaskSequencer::ReleaseTickGroup()
>   [d:\build++ue4+release-4.19+compile\sync\engine\source\runtime\engine\private\ticktaskmanager.cpp:542]
>   UE4Editor_Engine!FTickTaskManager::RunTickGroup()
>   [d:\build++ue4+release-4.19+compile\sync\engine\source\runtime\engine\private\ticktaskmanager.cpp:1449]
>   UE4Editor_Engine!UWorld::RunTickGroup()
>   [d:\build++ue4+release-4.19+compile\sync\engine\source\runtime\engine\private\leveltick.cpp:770]
>   UE4Editor_Engine!UWorld::Tick()
>   [d:\build++ue4+release-4.19+compile\sync\engine\source\runtime\engine\private\leveltick.cpp:1429] UE4Editor_UnrealEd!UEditorEngine::Tick()
>   [d:\build++ue4+release-4.19+compile\sync\engine\source\editor\unrealed\private\editorengine.cpp:1693]
>   UE4Editor_UnrealEd!UUnrealEdEngine::Tick()
>   [d:\build++ue4+release-4.19+compile\sync\engine\source\editor\unrealed\private\unrealedengine.cpp:401]
>   UE4Editor!FEngineLoop::Tick()
>   [d:\build++ue4+release-4.19+compile\sync\engine\source\runtime\launch\private\launchengineloop.cpp:3339]
>   UE4Editor!GuardedMain()
>   [d:\build++ue4+release-4.19+compile\sync\engine\source\runtime\launch\private\launch.cpp:166] UE4Editor!GuardedMainWrapper()
>   [d:\build++ue4+release-4.19+compile\sync\engine\source\runtime\launch\private\windows\launchwindows.cpp:144]
>   UE4Editor!WinMain()
>   [d:\build++ue4+release-4.19+compile\sync\engine\source\runtime\launch\private\windows\launchwindows.cpp:223]
>   UE4Editor!__scrt_common_main_seh()
>   [f:\dd\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\startup\exe_common.inl:253] kernel32
>   ntdll

Comment: The question is too broad. Given that all we know from your description is we need some nearest neighbor algorithm, we can offer nothing. You will at the very least need to specify approximately the problem size, the constraints on time and space and whatever other quirk there is.

Comment: Edited the post with a attempt on a better explanation @PasserBy

Comment: Seems like you are trying to access a null pointer. You need to see which UObject reference you are using is null. You can surround your pointers with the ensure() assertion if they are always supposed to have a value when used. Just make sure you remove it after debugging. I personally prefer to protect my pointers with if statements.

Comment: @Balgy Hi, Thanks for the comment! I am protecting it with if statements let alone ensure statements. The UObject just gets destroyed after the ensure happened and when it was a valid pointer. So like: the if ensure fires --> UObject gets destroyed --> It tries to get the distance but it's trying toget it from a destroyed uobject. The problem is there's no exact 'time' the object get's destroyed that can prevent the error. So i'm looking into Enviroment Querying and Blackboards for a solution.

Comment: if you want a really rough and temporary workaround, unreal lets you add objects to the root set of garbage collection.

Comment: What is `TargetTank`? How is it declared? Is it a `UPROPERTY`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for nullptr.

```
if (OtherActor != nullptr)
{    
         // Your code here    
}
```

EDIT: Not only on line 13, also on lines 18, 23 (and probably more lines since I can't see entire code on the screenshot)

If you need detailed explanation why you need to use nullptr and where I can edit this question

EDIT2: I didn't notice it was Unreal Code, can you provide us with code on line:

`ATankAIController::GetClosestEnemyTank()` line 70, and
`ATankAIController::Tick()` line 37. Basically if possible entire methods. The problem still is nullptr.

Comment: The code you're referring to is the engine code (AActor class), not the OP's code.

Comment: @Rotem you were right, i didn't notice. I edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

1. As you only have 12 tanks here, so it's OK to iterate all the tanks and calculate the distance directly. I would also do it like this in this situation.
2. Inside the definition of `GetDistanceTo`, I suggest you use `IsValid()` to check if `OtherActor` is valid or not. It's safer, and it's the recommended way to check the validation of Actors.
3. I would also suggest you to use `TActorIterator`, not `TObjectIterator`. [Because it provides the safety of not accessing actors that are pending kill](https://wiki.unrealengine.com/Iterators:_Object_%26_Actor_Iterators,_Optional_Class_Scope_For_Faster_Search).
4. About the crash here, the `PossessedTank` or/and `PendingTarget` might be an invalid pointer here depending on how you define and operate them. I don't see the complete code, but according to the call stack, I think `PendingTarget` is invalid here, that's why the program crashes.